# Multiple split tokens using boost::is_any_of

Tags: c++, string, boost, stl

I am unsure how to use `boost::is_any_of` to split a string using a set of characters, any ONE of which should split the string.

I wanted to do something like this as I understood the is_any_of function takes a Set parameter.

```
std::string s_line = line = "Please, split|this    string";

std::set<std::string> delims;
delims.insert("\t");
delims.insert(",");
delims.insert("|");

std::vector<std::string> line_parts;
boost::split ( line_parts, s_line, boost::is_any_of(delims));
```

However this produces a list of boost/STD errors.
Should I persist with `is_any_of` or is there a better way to do this eg. using a regex split?

Comment: It's a shame that `is_any_of` doesn't take an iterator range.

Answer (score 34):

You shall try this:

```
boost::split(line_parts, s_line, boost::is_any_of("\t,|"));
```

Answer (score 12):

Your first line is not valid C++ syntax without a pre-existing variable named `line`, and `boost::is_any_of` does not take a `std::set` as a constructor parameter.

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s_line = "Please, split|this\tstring";
    std::string delims = "\t,|";

    std::vector<std::string> line_parts;
    boost::split(line_parts, s_line, boost::is_any_of(delims));

    std::copy(
        line_parts.begin(),
        line_parts.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "/")
    );

    // output: `Please/ split/this/string/`
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The main issue is that `boost::is_any_of` takes a `std::string` or a `char*` as the parameter. Not a `std::set<std::string>`.

You should define `delims` as `std::string delims = "\t,|"` and then it will work.